# Second monitor display is not active after windows update

Tags: windows-10, display, windows-update, display-adapter

A few days ago, my Microsoft Surface Pro 4 was connected to a TV via a Mini Displayport to HDMI adapter and an HDMI cable. My PC ran out of power and shutdown. I started the PC again and an update was required. After this update, there was no signal sent to the TV.

In **Settings >> System >> Display >> Advanced display settings**, I found that the second display is detected but is not active.

In **Win+P** it is possible for me to change the different display configurations even though nothing happens when changed.

In **Settings >> System >> Display** it is not possible to select other display configurations than "Show only on 1". If others are selected the "Keep these changes"-dialogue box is displayed, and no matter what I select here, does the configuration go back to "Show only on 1".

What I have tried so far:

- Rolled back Display Adapter driver.
- Automatic update of the Display Adapter driver in Device Manager.
- Changed the resolution and scaling settings.
- Tried a different monitor. Using Mini Displayport to VGA adapter and a VGA-cable.
- Manual update of the Display Adapter driver in Device Manager with the newest driver from Intel. (After uninstall and deletion of the already installed driver)
- Manual update of the Display Adapter driver in Device Manager with multiple older versions of drivers from Intel. (After uninstall and deletion of the already installed driver)
- Restored by System restore but can not go far enough back.

I hope that you guys can give me the answers I need.

Comment: If System Restore wasn't disabled, rollback to a restore point from before this happened.

Comment: Have you tried connecting the mini-DP port to an actual DP display yet? DP requires connection sensing so might not activate the display until the port is active on a true DP device.